# Do Rave Master and Fairy Tail share the same world?

Tags: fairy-tail, rave-master

There's a crossover work for Fairy Tail and Rave Master called Fairy Tail X Rave. Do these two series share the same world or is it just for the sake of crossover? They even have Dark Bring (Rave) and Magic (Fairy Tail) together.

[image]
<sub>On the left with pink hair: Natsu - Fairy Tail. On the right with silver hair: Haru - Rave</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure if they share the same world but they were done by the same man though. xD~ Although I always prefered Fairy Tail. Lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two series are by the same mangaka - Hiro Mashima - so it was this that allowed for the easy crossover OVA, as there were no copyright or licensing discussions that had to be made.

The two series do not share the same world. Rave master takes place primarily in the *Continent of Luka*, whereas Fairy Tail takes place in *Earth Land*.

I'm unsure of the overall world name for Rave Master, but there is no *Luka* in *Earth Land* and the maps look quite different.

[image]

Rave Master World Map

[image]

Fairy Tail World Map

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the worlds are not the same but parallel like Edolas. The fact that the rave people came to fairy tail was probably by mistake just how some of the Edolas people got to earth-land. The two anime/ manga are written by the same man, but the fact he linked them could be seen as an Easter egg as some or no ova's are cannon, however in my personal opinion weather it's an OVA or not, the fact that they linked is clear enough to me that they are in fact parallel. However many things are the same in both animes like the jiggle but gang, indicating to me once again it is parallel and characters can move from one place to another. :) 
Nyaaaa~

Comment: They also share Ploo. Lucy summons him often enough, and it is Ploo from Rave Master, at least from him deflating in hot water and other silliness that we have seen in the anime.

Answer (score 0):

No, they only share the same mangaka and drawing style. In both, the Etherion is present. It is also similar but not the same thing.

In both we see parallel twin worlds, but they are differently meant.